# Изменения строки в функции

Tags: c, строки

Собственно задание заключается в написании функции, которая заменяет содержимое указанной строки этой же строкой, но с обратным порядком следования символов.
Почему строка не переворачивается?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "s_gets.h"
#define SIZE 30

void revers(char *);

int main(){
    char str[SIZE];
    s_gets(str, SIZE);
    revers(str);
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}

void revers(char * str){
    int size_ = strlen(str) - 1;
    char tmp;
    for(int i = size_; i >= 0; i--){
        tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[size_ - i];
        str[size_ - i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: переворачивается, а потом назад i >= size_/2 - примерно так, учитывай только что длина может быть четная и нет

Answer (score 3):

Вы ее переворачиваете 2 раза:

```
for(int i = size_; i >= 0; i--)
{
    tmp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[size_ - i];
    str[size_ - i] = tmp;
}
```

Когда `i` принимает некоторое значение `j`, и когда `size_-j`.

Ограничьтесь одном проходом.

```
for(int i = size_, j = 0; i > j; i--, j++)
{
    tmp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = tmp;
}
```